# annotator is working when the selected content annotator editor enabled but my requirement is on right click annotator should enabled how answers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

annotator offline plugin  if we selected some content annotator editor is showing but i want code to implement on right click it has to open the annotator editor

$(function () {

```
//$(document).ready( function (){
    $.contextMenu({// this is for on right click option showing like Annotator 
        selector: '.context-menu-one',
        callback: function (key, options) {
            var m = "clicked: " + key;

            $(".annotator-outer").css({ 'display': 'block' });
        },
        items: {
            "annotator": { name: "Annotator" },
        }
    })
})  


var content = $("#content").annotator(); // this is for loading the annotator script call function
content.annotator('addPlugin', 'Offline', {
    online: function () {
        $("#status").text("Online");
    },
    offline: function () {
        $("#status").text("Offline");
    }
});
var annotator = content.data('annotator');

$("#clear-storage").click(function () {
    if (annotator) {
        annotator.plugins.Offline.store.clear()
    }
});
```

annotator is working when the selected content annotator editor enabled but my requirement is on right click annotator should enabled how can i implement